# Repeat of dataframe columns by list or vector in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rep

I have a `df` (dataframe):

```
df=data.frame(V1=c(10,20,10,20),V2=c(20,30,20,30),V3=c(20,10,20,10))
> df
  V1 V2 V3
1 10 20 20
2 20 30 10
3 10 20 20
4 20 30 10
```

I have a vector `v<-list(1,3,2)`
Each element represents the number of repetition of relevant column.
I would like to create following `df` and `V` the dataframe `dfV`:

```
> dfV
      V1 V2_1 V2_2 V2_3 V3_1 V3_2
    1 10  20   20  20   20   20
    2 20  30   30  30   10   10
    3 10  20   20  20   20   20
    4 20  30   30  30   10   10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new_df <- NULL
for (i in 1:ncol(df)){
 replicate_col <- replicate(v[i], df[,i])
 new_df <- cbind(new_df, replicate_col)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rep`

```
df[rep(names(df), v)]
```